# Wordpress Migration loosing .css, .js and other major information

Tags: wordpress, migration

After migrate to the Umbler server I am getting some errors in my site. When I open it, the "customize" configurations made in the past server where not working.

When I try to open the path "nutti.com.br/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper-child/" I get the 403 error, which does not happen in the previous server. I have changed the access rights in FileZilla to 755 for folders and 644 for files.

I do not know what can I do, the error 403 remains and my site is getting some images references from the father theme (shopkeeper), when it should be getting from the child theme (shopkeeper-child).

Answer (score 1):

These are the most common incarnations of 403 Forbidden errors:

**403 Forbidden Errors Due To**

*HTTP 403
Forbidden: You don't have permission to access [directory] on this server
Forbidden

Error 403
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

Error 403 - Forbidden
HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden*

Source - https://www.lifewire.com/403-forbidden-error-explained-2617989